# Migrating form GlassFish V2.x to GlassFish V3.0

Tags: jsf-2

My product is build on glassFish V2.x and IDE is NetBeans 6.9.1. but now client is asking for GlassFish V3.0 .
in glassfish v2.x , jsf version is 1.2 but in glassfish v3, jsf version is 2.0. so could anybody  tell me what are the requires changes i should do.
 (Note in my apllication 70% of pages(like new.jsp, edit.jsp, list.jsp ) were build dynamically ) by considering this note please provide the information.
thanks & regards,
sridhar kosna.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

Comment: Don't put `[closed]` in title yourself. This makes no sense. Just accept an answer (you already did) and move on. If you accept an answer, then the question will appear in the listing with slight different colors which indicate that there's an accepted answer. That's more than sufficient.

Comment: sridhar: Please read the above comment. Do not put `[closed]` in title yourself. This has an entirely different meaning than a finished question. If you want to distinguish questions with or without an accepted answer, just look at the color of the answer count in the question listing. If it's yellow, then it has an accepted answer. If it's white, then it doesn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the application as-is on GlassFish 3.1.1?

Check out this link for upgrades to the runtime: http://blogs.oracle.com/bobby/entry/moving_on_up_upgrading_to

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it didnt useful to me. My requirement is like already built application which was in glassFish V2.x that should be deployed in glassFish V3.0 please give me some suggestions on this.@sridharKosna

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by migrating richfaces from V 3.3.1 to V3.3.3

Comment: and provided ID's to all dynamic components there by solving duplicate Exception problem. 2) For rich calendar we should not add onchange event to the calendar component directly. We need to  put in the facets MAP of that Component then only the date numbers and other functionality will work properly